# Encrypt with CryptoJS to Decypt with openssl_decrypt on PHP 7 returns always false

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

I need in my front (ionic) encrypt a UUID to send it to the backend.

I use CryptoJS, this is my code to encrypt the UUID.

```
const UUID = 'ABCD1234';
const privateKey = 'f38d09938ead31a57eca34d2a0df1c44';   
const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(privateKey, salt, {
  hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512,
  keySize: 4,
  iterations: 1
});
const encripted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(UUID, key, {
  iv
});
const cp = {};
cp.mid = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encripted.ciphertext);
cp.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv);
cp.s = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);
```

So I send the CP in headers to the server (Slim Framework 3).

I receive like this:

```
$mid = $request->getHeader('HEADER-MID')[0];
$iv = $request->getHeader('HEADER-IV')[0];
$salt = $request->getHeader('HEADER-S')[0];

//Example Data Received
//mid: losv78Amn1zpgRe5/4hYFA==
//iv: 2d198339d178c053c37e36b7d03e8a3b
//salt: fb07dd1f61d72148bc1423af8cd1f295

$ct = base64_decode($mid);
$salt = hex2bin($salt);
$iv = hex2bin($iv);

$key = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $privateKey, $salt, 1, 32);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'AES-256-CBC', hex2bin($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

The key is generated correctly in back and front.

But the openssl_decrypt function return false and with openssl_error_string() get this:

```
error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If you're using HTTPS (which you should be), this is superfluous.

Comment: I need a layer of protection in my app because there are no login and I need indetify a user and change his properties, etc...

Comment: What does this approach do that HTTPS doesn't?

Comment: At this moment I can't use SSL Pinning, this is a momentary solution and I will change it when I can to HTTPS.

Comment: As a result of your answer I have searched a little more about the subject, and I have seen that indeed, in the case of my project, I don't require encryption beyond the one that gives me https at the moment.
Thanks.